# Problems with Apache htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have this htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^/4b/ / [R=301,L]

    # This portion checks for the presence of maintenance.enable to toggle
    # maintenance mode
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.html -f
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.enable -f
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance.html [R=503,L]
    ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
    Header Set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-store"

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't match the URL http://test.com/4b/ or http://test.com/4b -- instead, it gives me a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I added an extra `/` in `^/4b/` when it should have been just `^4b/`